# How can I get the Product Key with Autopsy or FTK viewer?

Tags: windows, disk-image, forensics

I have a disk image divided in 4 files, image.E01, image.E02, image.E03 and image.E04. I created a case in autopsy and I'm trying to recover the Product ID and the Product Key.

The product ID I already found it in the Operating System Information section, but the product key is not there. I saw I could use RegRipper to recover it but I cannot use RegRipper from autopsy and I dont know how to get with RegRipper to the System folder any other way.

I also tried with FTK viewer but I don't know where to look either.

Is possible to recover this information? If the answer is affirmative, where can I find it and how?